# Amazon EC2 multiple private IP addresses per instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip-address

I have a scenario where an application requires multiple private IP addresses but does not require the resources of multiple instances.

In this case, I would like to run multiple jboss instances on the same EC2 instance *without* port mangling.

I've seem threads up to 2009 that stated this is not possible, checking if this has changed.

EDIT: I want to re-emphasize the private IP address is the question, not the elastic/public IP address. I am sorry I did not make this more specific.

Comment: Should be moved to serverfault

Comment: I don't understand the negativity with the down votes. It's a valid question for stackoverflow. There are tons of ec2 related questions here.

Comment: The specifics of the question is with regards to private IP addresses, not the Elastic/public IP addresses which has already been addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, It's possible to create ENI(elastic network interface) with 1 public, 1 primary private and 1 or more secondary private IP addresses and then this ENI can be attached to EC2 instance.

For more info please refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is still the case. Quoting from the [Amazon EC2 Elastic IP Addresses - FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346):

> **Can an instance have more than one Elastic IP or Public IP?**
>
> Today, an instance can only have one Internet routable IP address. If an Elastic IP is mapped to an instance its existing Public IP address mapping is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, it's still not possible.

Some people run vserver or UML on an ec2 instance. You could set up various environments in there and then port forward from the host, etc. but that seems overcomplicated (*IMHO*).